# Is there any way to manually control the displays of a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I have a recurring problem that windows refuses to acknowledge that the physical displays I have connected to it are there. It refuses to detect them, or even the port they are on. It won't let me set the resolution of displays it hasn't detected and it won't even show me the port I've connected the display to, though it does mention "Mobile PC Display", which is odd as this is a desktop PC!

All I want is to output my primary desktop to one discrete graphics DVI port, the first extended desktop to the other discrete graphics DVI port and a third extended desktop to the DVI port of my integrated graphics.

I know this is physically possible because I have managed to get this setup running in the past, but however it happened (perhaps a driver 'update') I can't find the combination of magic runes needed to get it to work now.

So, is there any way to manually control the displays of a Windows 7 PC?

If I were using Linux, I would just set up my xorg.conf to force the resolution I want from the displays I want and be done with it, but Windows appears to be too clever by half.